# Multiple file upload with paperclip in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's imagine that i have two model's:

```
car, and car photo's
```

count of this photo could be 0, 1 or even 100? so i need to do ajax photo uploading, but how could i do, that for example i render form:

```
= form_for @car do |f|
   fields....
```

and in that form i have partial, when i click add photo i get one more file_field area and how to submit form @car with many other sub-forms @car_photo ?

how to project this logic? how is better, and how to do? Any advice would be great )

for example here: 
http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/   it's only selecting multifiles, but i need to add partial logic, when i click add_photo i get filefield area, where i could select file, and then when i submite form i get  all this photos submited to..

Comment: I had such a problem month ago. So I created a "Gallery" model for my products (your cars). Then set "product has_one gallery". After that I created an "Image" model. Then set "gallery has_many images". After front-end job, now in my form for products I have a gallery. And for that gallery I am uploading images one by one with "add image" button and then pop-up with paperclip uploader. Maybe it's not the best solution :)

Comment: maybe you could give a part of code "images one by one with "add image" button and then pop-up with paperclip uploader."   to see how to code it

Comment: I was using rails_admin. Take a look of this screenshots: http://awesomescreenshot.com/02c2hc684c
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f12hc6c13
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0582hc6pd0
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0992hc6uc3